# C++ Calling methods with same signature but different scope

Tags: c++, tinyxml

I'm working on a project with TinyXML2. I'm trying to call the method **XMLAttribute* FindAttribute( const char* name )**

This method is defined by the implementation as:

```
public : 
const XMLAttribute* FindAttribute( const char* name ) const;

private :
XMLAttribute* FindAttribute( const char* name );
```

I am a bit confused how as to how a method can have the same signature in both public and private scopes. I can only guess that it does not, although I don't really understant the const part at the end of the public definition . However, I need to call the public method but g++ sais "**tinyxml2::XMLElement::FindAttribute(const char*) is private**"

How can I call the public method, and what does the const part at the end of the method prototype do?

Comment: Yes, this is to do with the trailing `const`, not `public`/`private`. If you imagine the implicit `this*` that is passed to these functions, it is like 2 functions `foo(T *this)` and `foo(T const *this)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Functions can be overloaded based on their `const`ness alone. This is an important feature of C++.

```
// const member function:
const XMLAttribute* FindAttribute( const char* name ) const;

// non-const member function
XMLAttribute* FindAttribute( const char* name );
```

In this case, the `const` that makes the functions different is the `const` following the parentheses. The `const` before the parenthesis does not belong to the method signature whilst the `const` that follows the parenthesis does. This latter use of `const` specifies which member functions may be called from `const` objects and which may not. In other words, it specifies the contract for `const` objects.

If you have a `const` object, the `const` method will be called:

```
const MyObject cObj;
cObj.FindAttribute("cats");
// const method will be called
```

If you have a non-`const` object, the compiler will look for a non-`const` method and call it. If it does not exist, it will look for a `const` method and call that. The compiler works this way because it is legal to call `const` member functions from non-`const` objects, but it is illegal to call non-`const` member functions from `const` objects.

```
MyObject obj;
obj.FindAttribute("cats");
// non-const method will be called
// if it does not exist the compiler will look for a const version
```

Comment: +1 for samples and detailed explanation how the compiler resolves to the public method available.

Answer (score 3):

> I am a bit confused how as to how a method can have the same signature in both public and private scopes.

They don't have the same signature actually

```
const XMLAttribute* FindAttribute( const char* name ) const;
                                                   // ^^^^^^
```

the public method is applicable for `const` access to the containing class. This counts for the function signature uniqueness.